# jQuery: looking for gallery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, gallery

i'm looking for a jQuery gallery with the following features:
- scrollable thumbnails (horizontal)
- fading transition when clicking
- extra lightbox on the big picture for full view

thanks

Comment: http://www.webdesignshock.com/showcase/100-best-jquery-image-gallery-plugins/

Comment: Look at this gallery, that i wrote few days ago. It very similar to what google use: https://github.com/creotiv/jquery-photowall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never saw good jquery gallery plugin with features you want, but you can take http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/ and add extra lightbox for big image.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty gallery perhaps?
http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

I also really like Galeria:
http://galleria.aino.se/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the jquery plugin :
http://demo.awkward.se/showcase/index2.html
according to your requirement you'll need to add lightbox.